# T-SQL | 3 Tables, Optional Joins, Confused

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an `orders` table which lists stores what parts where deleted, removed and installed on each job.

```
--Deleted Items on a order.
DECLARE @Deleted TABLE (ID int, Item int);

INSERT INTO @Deleted (ID, Item)
VALUES (1, 12345), (2, 12345);

-- Removed Items on a order
DECLARE @Removed TABLE (ID int, Item int);

INSERT INTO @Removed (ID, Item)
VALUES(3, 12345), (4, 67891);

--Installed items on a order
DECLARE @Installed TABLE (ID int, Item int);

INSERT INTO @Installed(ID, Item)
VALUES(1, 12345), (2, 67891), (3, 12345), (4, 12345), (4, 67891);
```

I need the following result set:

```
--Required Result Set

    /*

        ID  |     DEL / REM   |   Installed | Match |
        1   |     12345     |   12345       |   1   |
        2   |     12345     |   67891       |   0   |
        3   |     12345     |   12345       |   1   |
        4   |     67891     |   67891       |   1   |
        4   |     NULL      |   12345       |   0   |

    */
```

The main problem I have with all this is order 4. There is a match on one of the parts installed but not the second. So I need to say where **ID  = ID** AND IF POSSIBLE **Item = Item** OR just Item if it doesn't match.

I know that the maximum number of alternate installed items are two, so for each order, there will be a maximum of 2 different Item number installed (currently).

I know there also may be multiple deleted or removed items (not depicted above).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify "ID = ID AND IF POSSIBLE Item = Item OR just Item if it doesn't match". I can't see how you intend to reach your required result set.

Comment: I think that,s my problem. ID is an OrderID there can be multiple per table. I want to say, if an item was fitted where the OrderID AND the Item match, then Match = 1 or just OrderID = OrderID. (Relating to ID 4) Line 1 is OrderID and Item match, 2nd row is Only the ID matched and the Item that hasn't matched yet is returned.

Comment: Well how can an item be deleted or removed if it was never added/installed? Is there just a part table that we aren't seeing? Can you give us the full orders table? Your current tables make this nearly impossible without getting ugly/slow